# phpmyadmin login on 8080 broken?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, phpmyadmin

typical stack, Nginx, varnish, php 7.

If I set the vhost in nginx to 80 I can login without difficulty.  If I move it to 8080 I cant (verified varnish/nginx listening on correct port when troubleshooting.  no issues with wordpress, also tried adminer which works fine, may just use that or another alternative at this point

the blofish secret is set in config.inc.php and PmaAbsoluteUri was set as well, using cookie auth.  php can write to the session directory, mcrypt is enabled and present in phpinfo

I configured varnish to ignore the 
I've run out of productive troubleshooting.

using the latest phpmyadmin version directly from the official site

Comment: How are you attempting to access phpmyadmin? What error message are you getting? What do your logs say ?

Comment: phpmyadmin is on a subomain with the vhost pointed at the doc root (no subdir) no nginx or php errors in the logs (it eventually get a  connection timeout

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: How are you attempting to access phpmyadmin?
Answer: Type the URLin the address bar of a browser (firefox|chrome|ie What error message are you getting? 
As previously stated "connection timeout"
What do your logs 
as previously stated no nginx or php errors  I could redact and pastebin some essentially empty logs I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

critical pieces to the answer:

As I have it behind varnish its on port 8080.

the Nginx config needs to be edited to add the following after `include fastcgi_params;`

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80;
```

Also in Varnish4 vcl, return(pass) isn't good enough as the rest of the routines run a common wordpress vcl will strip the phpmyadmin cookie!, use return(pipe) instead (lots of old google results use pass)

finally, the varnish log logs as http://url (at least in my custom logging format), don't let that mislead you:

```
if (req.http.Host == "www.domain.com) {
return (pipe);
```

If you suspect its not catching a url / regex, confirm by sticking a `return(pipe);` immediately following `sub vcl_recv {`

no channges to proypass or redirect off are needed, no need to add a vcl_fetch sub to the varnish config.

Hope this helps someone else, I scoured google and found dozens of "solutions" that did not work.